# Downloading Images from Parse with Onclick

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to download images from parse cloud based on the options which are provided from the parse. When the users selects any of this desired options he should be able to download the images from the Parse cloud accordingly.

I have set @OnCLick to Layout which holds the options which are loaded from parse cloud.

R.id coupon is assigned to item_coupon_holder. And I want to add OnClick to the Coupon Holder so when the user click on that holder it download Images From the Parse Cloud. So can anyone help me how should I go about with it.

```
 @OnClick(R.id.coupon_view)
    public void done(ParseObject object,
                     ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Locate the column named "ImageName" and set
        // the string
        ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object
                .get("Coupons");
        fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

            public void done (byte[] data,
                             ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("test",
                            "We've got data in data.");
                    // Decode the Byte[] into
                    // Bitmap
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeByteArray(
                                    data, 0,
                                    data.length);

                    // Get the ImageView from
                    // main.xml
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivTakenPhoto);

                    // Set the Bitmap into the
                    // ImageView
                    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    // Close progress dialog
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

But it gives error

> Error:(434, 17) error: @OnClick methods can have at most 1
>   parameter(s). (com.google.peep.activity.TakePhotoActivity.done)

This is my ViewHolder which holds the options which will be loaded from parse.

```
@Layout(R.layout.item_coupon_holder)
public class CouponsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CouponsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        placename = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_name);
    }

    @ParseName("PlaceName")
    public TextView placename;
}
```

Comment: u want to fetch image from the parse table ?